# java work with redis from several app instances

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

My aim is to work with general instance of Redis server from several app instances (read-write access). I need it to share web session id and session meta information between several web application servers.

When only one instance of web app is up, everything is going fine, but when second instance initialized, db is flushed, so data inserted by first app is gone. I tried out 2 ways of connection establishment:

with spring

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            config.getString(Constants.REDIS_CONFIG_FILE));
    this.redisTemplate = (RedisTemplate) context.getBean("redisTemplate");

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:use-pool="true" p:host-name="${oiosaml-sp.sessionhandler.redis.url}"
      p:port="${oiosaml-sp.sessionhandler.redis.port}"/>

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>
```

and with jedis

```
    String redisUrl = config.getString(Constants.REDIS_URL);
    String redisPort = config.getString(Constants.REDIS_PORT);
    if (redisUrl == null || redisPort == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                PROPERTY_IS_NOT_SET_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(MAX_CONNECTION_AMOUNT);
    this.pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, redisUrl,
            Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
```

But in both variant i have the same issue that db is flushed when connection from second instance of app is established. And it looks like redis-server doesn't work properly in this situation. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i has not  experience of spring redis template,but your jedis code impossible cause this problem.
redis-server also impossible flush db auto.
the only possible reason is your code flush db on special condation. 
please try restart your first app instance and see whats happens.

Comment: You are right. Just now accidentally found out a problem. That was in my implementation of SP filter session handler, that used my redis connection pool. Inside filter resetReplayProtection method was called during application initialization and it flushed my db. Thank you for participation anyway.